# How is Coronavirus going to effect your game and the poker industry?

Tags: pre-flop

Today Trump announced a travel ban from Europe. A quick check on Bravo showed Aria and Bellagio at about half of the number of games I would expect. I saw news that Macau shut down all the casinos there a week ago. For me personally I am running through my head that I need to quit the dealing job and stay away from live poker.

The question is how is the Coronavirus going to effect you and your poker playing?

And contained in that can be these questions;

So how is it going to effect the time you spend at a poker table?

If your a pro are you going to continue trying to make a living?

Anybody here planning on coming to the WSOP cancel plans?

Are we even going to be able to find a live game as the panic spreads?

Las Vegas update 3/15. MGM announces layoffs and closures of restaurants, night clubs. The North valet closed at Bellagio. Most shows have gone dark until further notice, Including cirque de soleil, Penn and Teller and more are coming. Rumors heard; 2% occupancy last night at Bellagio. Aria, Bellagio and other MGM poker rooms may be closed soon. Most conventions (if not all) have been cancelled and convention workers have been sent home.

12 hours later 3/15 MGM and Wynn announce property closures.

3/18 Nevada Gaming is closed for the next thirty days.

3/20 quick check of bravo shows one game in the US at motor city Casino in Detroit. I would just like to say to all the players and management at Motor City Casino, you are just stupid clueless people, shame on you.

Comment: Interesting question but I don't really think anyone can really know. The only thing to say with certainty is that it'll effect the game simply because it's effecting the global economy. For me I'm avoiding live play currently. I think depending on how long things last for, you very well may see some card rooms forced to close for good.

Answer (score 3):

Well Grinch we know now. I live less then two miles from the Las Vegas strip, nearest game is in Arizona, 250 miles away according to bravo. If I didn't like that game I would have to go to Detroit 1800 miles. I would hope these narcissistic operators close or get closed soon.

I really don't know why anybody is playing anywhere. Makes me think that maybe gamblers anonymous should add a 21st question, "Did you play live poker during the Corona Virus world wide Pandemic?"

If we play we play online for awhile.

Comment: I'd really like to see the states legalise online play again across country, I think it'd go a long way to help with the social distancing. Yeah we do know now alright :D. It's a shame though as many of my friends still in Vegas as dealers have been laid off due to this. I mean right decision to close, but not great to fire everyone. The Wynn at least are giving a few weeks pay.

Comment: Well I am one that got laid off from Bellagio. Yeah to the Wynn, but in poker almost everyone is part time at the Wynn, MGM properties and others and none of the on calls are getting pay. I was happy to get laid off, I did not want to be in there. Had been calling in hoping I did not get fired before a layoff came. I am lucky I am ok with cash and income, but most of the on calls were barely floating and are going to be hard pressed until the storm passes.

Comment: Sorry to hear you got laid off because of it! I've heard a few rooms off the strip are still open as of last week, maybe it's changed by my friend was in Red Rock working there said they were only laying off the on-call but staying open.

Comment: they closed everything over a week ago.

Comment: Well I guess that's good, stay safe as best as you can anyway!